# How can I get the explorer process back which has gone missing?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

When I boot up the system stalls just past the welcome screen. I.e. the welcome screen is replaced by a blank screen sporting my custom background colour.  Then it halts and won't go any further. I can run the task manager which shows that the explorer.exe process is missing.  From the task manager I can run some programs but not explorer.exe.  The program itself is in its proper place: C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\explorer.exe and C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe. I stress that this is NOT a virus for it occurs in a newly installed system without connection to the internet and the few programs I did install are guaranteed virus-free. The culprit is probably one of my own batch scripts used for installing programs, but that's another issue. For the moment I would just like to know how I can get the explorer process up and running again.

Comment: I would open a command prompt `cmd.exe` and then type `explorer`, on the off chance that it prints some diagnostic information regarding *why* it does not want to start up.

Comment: No, that didn't do the trick. Tried it both with and without the exe extension. No information at all, diagnostic or otherwise, nada!

Comment: Since you mentioned a batch script that could have been the culprit, how about we explore (lol) how it may have caused the disappearance of Explorer.exe?

Comment: The code likely to be responsible, kills explorer.exe which is followed by importing a key to restore taskbar settings. Windows then restores explorer.exe automatically.   
Perhaps it should be followed explicitly with a START command to reinstate explorer.exe.

The fault is difficult to test because it is intermittent and when the fault does occur, the entire system has to be reinstalled.  Besides, because of its intermittency, one can never be sure that a cure really is effective.

Comment: It's not just these two batch scripts that cause the problem, others do it as well so it would seem to be a bug in the batch process itself.